# Java how to log set input

Tags: java

How do i log what goes in to the followin method?

```
myclass.setUrl(input.substring(ind, ind += 42).trim());
```

Using system.out is not possible, since void type is not allowed here.

Comment: 1. compute the value, assign it to a variable. 2. log that variable. 3. call the method, using the variable as the argument.

Comment: How to assing it to a variable since void cannot be converted to string?

Comment: You are not passing `void` into that method. You can't pass `void` to a method. Can you explain *what exactly* you want to log in this case?

Comment: `setUrl(input.substring(ind, ind += 42).trim());` sets a string to myclass from place 42. I want to log what goes in on the set method without logging getMethod. Basically what the line does.

Comment: setUrl is setting something, it should have a get method that reads the url like getUrl, call it after set and log the value. or do as the first comment says save substring result into a variable log the variable and then pass it to setUrl.

Comment: You pass in `input.substring(ind, ind += 42).trim()` to that method. Assign that to a variable. Log that variable. Then call `setUrl(yourVariable)`. What's wrong with that approach?
Do you understand the distinction of "the method that you call" and "the value that you pass to it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log what you are setting the URL as, which is what I'm assuming you are doing, you would have to set your url to a variable and log it.

```
String urlVar = input.substring(ind, ind += 42).trim();
System.out.println(urlVar); //Or log(urlVar);
myclass.setUrl(urlVar);
```

Alternatively you could add a print/log statement in your setUrl(String urlVal) method. This would probably be the cleanest way of doing this.

```
public void setUrl(String urlVal){
    System.out.println(urlVal);
    this.urlVal = urlVal;
}
```